# mysql-cli - force quit on timeout / connection drop

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line-interface, connection, timeout

I have set timeouts in `/etc/profile.d/` to disconnect inactive users using `TMOUT` and this works great however now I am seeing users just holding their connection open by keeping some foreground process open e.g. `mysql`.  I realise this could be anything `vim` / `less` / etc, however as the mysql-cli has options for various timeouts and reconnecting dropped connection (or not) has anyone discovered a way to forcably quit the mysql-cli on a broken connection / timeout thus dumping the user back into bash?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you need to inconvenience your users? Clearly they _want_ to have open idle connections. And who says I'm _not_ watching that `tail -f`? You might be able to find some way to do this, but then your users will just find some other way of keeping their connections open.

Comment: @MichaelHampton All your points are valid, however I know the users and it is not a case of _want_ but _forgetfulness_.  I know this as the users use laptops, have a connection open all day, take their laptop home.  I realise they there are many ways round this and they could use anything like `tail -f` or as in my supplied examples `vim` / `less` / etc to do this, hence why my question was directed specifically at the `mysql-cli` client but until they intentionally try and keep the connection open (which I will notice when use `w` and it not being the mysql client) I dont mind.